# Symfony Error when trying to get data in a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Symfony is tormenting my head right now. I'm trying to get data from a table where the column associates a relationship with an id from another table. Thats my controller function:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/proposta/{id}", defaults={"id"=null})
 */
public function mostraAction($id) {
    $model = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
    $lista = $model->getRepository('AppBundle:Propostes')->find($id);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $listaVotacions = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Votacions')->findByIdProposta($id);

    return $this->render(':Proposta:index.html.php',
    array('lista'=>$lista,'listaVotacions'=>$listaVotacions));
}
```

That's not working, when I execute this function, my server falls and I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.
```

That's my class of Votacions:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Votacions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="votacions")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VotacionsRepository")
 */
class Votacions
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Propostes")
     */
    private $idProposta;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Usuaris")
     */
    private $idUsuari;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vot", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $vot;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set idProposta
     *
     * @param integer $idProposta
     *
     * @return Votacions
     */
    public function setIdProposta($idProposta)
    {
        $this->idProposta = $idProposta;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idProposta
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdProposta()
    {
        return $this->idProposta;
    }

    /**
     * Set idUsuari
     *
     * @param integer $idUsuari
     *
     * @return Votacions
     */
    public function setIdUsuari($idUsuari)
    {
        $this->idUsuari = $idUsuari;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idUsuari
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdUsuari()
    {
        return $this->idUsuari;
    }

    /**
     * Set vot
     *
     * @param boolean $vot
     *
     * @return Votacions
     */
    public function setVot($vot)
    {
        $this->vot = $vot;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vot
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getVot()
    {
        return $this->vot;
    }
}
```

And this my repository Votacions:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class VotacionsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByIdProposta($id)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                    'SELECT * FROM AppBundle:Votacions WHERE idProposta ='.$id
                )->getResult();
    }
}
```

Someone could help me :(?

Thank you so much.

Carles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call only one time the "GetDoctrine"

-> find your lista object

-> Access idProposta from $lista object

-> the id from Proposta Entity

```
public function mostraAction($id) {
$model = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$lista = $model->getRepository('AppBundle:Votacions')->find($id);

$lista->getIdProposta()->getId();
 //..
return $this->render(':Proposta:index.html.php',
array('lista'=>$lista,'listaVotacions'=>$listaVotacions));
```

}

Comment: Sorry lista is also a query to find all. I update my function so u can see for wha is it. ur solution is not working too:(

Comment: Inside controler your can access   $listaVotacions->getIdProposta()->getWhateverName();

Comment: Inside twig template {{listaVotacions.idProposal.whateverName}}

Comment: The problem is that I can't get the value. When I do findBySomething in clases without relationships are working perfectly, when I try to use findBySomething in a class that has relationships is falling server and don't shows any error in php debug.

Comment: I update my answer check the query and tell me if this work